# How to iterate a request dynamically for each user in JMeter

Tags: loops, jmeter

I need to iterate a request multiple times in JMeter for different users. The iteration number differs for each users. For example: I need to iterate a request 5 times for first user, 3 times for second user and only 1 time for 3rd user and so on. How can we do this and how the input can be fed to the same. Is it possible to say read first 5 line for first user and next 3 lines for second user in csv data set config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can define the desired loops count for each user in the [CSV file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config,) or via [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
2. You can read the desired line from the CSV file using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) like:

   - `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(0),)}` - read 1st line
   - `${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(1),)}` - read 2nd line
   - etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784422/an-error-was-encountered-with-the-requested-page-in-jmeter-even-capture-variab

Dmitri T can you look into this ?

Comment: Here, i have used 1 user and using bean shell pre-processor i got the number of lines in the csv for 1 user and used loop controller to iterate based on the number of lines, but i need to run for more users and each user has different number of iteration then how can i give input for other users do i need to use multiple csv or within same i can attain the goal

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem. There could be many other solutions available in JMeter.

You can define the loop count associated with the users (threads) in a (User Parameters)[enter link description here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) Pre-processor.

[image]

> This panel allows you to specify a series of values for any User Variable. For each thread, the variable will be assigned one of the values from the series in sequence. If there are more threads than values, the values get re-used.

Then the requests can be placed within a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

[image]

The User Parameters component shall be placed within a JSR223 Sampler to ensure the values are initiated before the loop controller is reached. Also the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) shall be placed within a [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) to ensure the Sampler is executed only once.

Add `SampleResult.setIgnore()` in the JSR223 Sampler to avoid the sampler getting recorded into the test results.

[image]

**Test plan structure**

[image]

> [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) more suitable for large numbers of parameters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784422/an-error-was-encountered-with-the-requested-page-in-jmeter-even-capture-variab 

can you look into this ?

Comment: Let me check. Looks like you have to use a (JSON Extractor)[https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor] instead of a (Regular Expression Extractor)[https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor].